# Navicat Premium Essentials Wont SSH

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, navicat

Im trying to get Navicat Premium Essentials to ssh tunnel into my aws Ec2 server. to access Mysql DB hosted on there. The error is **Access denied. Authentication that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic**

I can ssh into the instance via terminal no problem. Key Permission is 400.

When I save the connection and reload it, the pem file is no longer loaded in the browser file box (not sure if this is how it is suppose to be for security reasons) I have copied the same login from ssh cmd to navicat.

User: centos

Ip: Ec IP (also tried public dns)

Pem file: same as the one used to SSH.

Both port 22 and 3306 are open to my IP address

Any ideas? I feel like Navicat isn't sending the Pem file with the ssh request.

**Mac:** Sierra 10.12.5

**Navicat** Essentials 12.0.9

**AWS** Centos ec2.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your `known_hosts` entry in `~/.ssh` ?

Comment: I just did, same error.

Comment: The "group" that you added your host to (network rules) .. Did you "apply" it to the EC2?

Comment: I did. Navicat as emailed me back and informed me that it is a bug with the product and I have asked which ver. is stable.

Answer (score 0):

Navicat has emailed me back and informed me that it is a problem with their product I have asked for them to send me the most stable version.